# SQL Server CTE select single tree branch structure upto the root

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to pass a parameter into a CTE that selects a node then selects its parent up to the root where the `parentId` is null?

In my code below if I pass in a parameter that selects Rain Coats and then recurses up the tree to mens wear where its `parentId` is null and selects all the nodes in that branch including children. Could someone help me with this please. My example just recurses and shows the depth

SQL example:

```
DECLARE @Department TABLE
(
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ParentId int NULL
)

INSERT INTO @Department SELECT 1, 'Toys', null
INSERT INTO @Department SELECT 2, 'Computers', null
INSERT INTO @Department SELECT 3, 'Consoles', 2
INSERT INTO @Department SELECT 4, 'PlayStation 3', 3
INSERT INTO @Department SELECT 5, 'Xbox 360', 2
INSERT INTO @Department SELECT 6, 'Games', 1
INSERT INTO @Department SELECT 7, 'Puzzles', 6
INSERT INTO @Department SELECT 8, 'Mens Wear', null
INSERT INTO @Department SELECT 9, 'Mens Clothing', 8
INSERT INTO @Department SELECT 10, 'Jackets', 9
INSERT INTO @Department SELECT 11, 'Rain Coats', 10

;WITH c 
AS
(
    SELECT Id, Name,1 AS Depth
    FROM @Department
    WHERE ParentId is null  

         UNION ALL

         SELECT t.Id, t.Name, c.Depth + 1 AS 'Level'
    FROM @Department T  
    JOIN c ON t.ParentId = c.Id

)
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Id = 3
```

Comment: What is the output of your current query and in what do you want? I don't understand what you want that isn't already in that query.

Comment: I want to pass in a parameter that selects a node and then traverse up the tree to its root in that branch with all the children

Comment: So if i select Rain Coats i want the procedure to go upward and select all parents to that node upto means wear where it's parent is null so this will include all children does that make sense

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your current CTE just shows all the items in the tree, with their `Depth` and all the other properties. As such, it works fine.

To do what you're looking for, you have to almost "invert" the CTE - grab the item you're interested in first, as the "anchor" of your CTE, and then "recurse up" to the root:

```
DECLARE @StartID INT = 11

;WITH c 
AS
(
    SELECT Id, ParentId, Name, 1 AS Depth
    FROM @Department
    WHERE Id = @startID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.Id, t.ParentId, t.Name, c.Depth + 1 AS 'Level'
    FROM @Department T  
    INNER JOIN c ON t.Id = c.ParentId
)
SELECT * 
FROM c
```

This will do what you're looking for and output:

```
Id ParentId  Name            Depth
11    10     Rain Coats        1
10     9     Jackets           2
 9     8     Mens Clothing     3
 8   NULL    Mens Wear         4
```

**Update**

For a reverse order of Depth you can use this:

```
;WITH c 
AS
(
    SELECT Id, ParentId, Name, 1 AS Depth
    FROM @Department
    WHERE Id = @startID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.Id, t.ParentId, t.Name, c.Depth + 1 AS 'Level'
    FROM @Department T  
    INNER JOIN c ON t.Id = c.ParentId
)
SELECT Id,
       ParentID, 
       Name,
       MAX(Depth) OVER() - Depth + 1 AS InverseDepth
FROM c
```

Output from this:

```
Id ParentId  Name            InverseDepth
11    10     Rain Coats        4
10     9     Jackets           3
 9     8     Mens Clothing     2
 8   NULL    Mens Wear         1
```

Comment: how do you change the depth in reverse order it backwards wear mens wear is 1 - 4 Rain Coats. and does this select all children uinder each node

Comment: @KDM: what do you mean by *select all children under each node* ?? You're walking up the tree from a given node - each node always has exactly one parent node, and that's what gets selected

Comment: @KDM -  You can use `row_number() over(order by Depth desc) as Depth` in the main query.

Comment: about 4 levels in the cte. in my orignal cteexample it depth is in reverse order

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson could you update my code with you're example with row_number please

Comment: @KDM - or even `max(Depth) over() - Depth + 1 as Depth`. Might be faster than `row_number`.

Comment: @KDM: Mikael Eriksson just added an `InverseDepth` column to the output of the ultimate select, to give you the "inverse" of the `Depth` column; but you cannot do this within the CTE since it's being built up recursively and cannot possibly know ahead of time how many levels of depth there will be for any given case....

Comment: @marc_s - I will leave this answer alone now and leave it up to you to rollback or leave it as is :). Did not mean to overwrite your modification. Did not actually see it.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, your CTE has the root as its anchor, and goes from parent to child in its recursive part. If you want the whole tree, you'll need to start at the child of interest, and work your way up. This is one way to do that. I have introduced a new column `StartingId` which remains constant as we walk up the tree - this is what we will select based on:

```
;WITH c 
AS
(
    SELECT Id AS StartingId, Id, ParentId, Name, 0 AS Height
    FROM @Department

    UNION ALL

    SELECT c.StartingId, p.Id, p.ParentId, p.Name, c.Height + 1 AS Height
    FROM @Department p INNER JOIN c ON p.Id = c.ParentId
)
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.StartingId = 11
```

gives

```
StartingId  Id          ParentId    Name                                   Height
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------------------------------------------
11          11          10          Rain Coats                             0
11          10          9           Jackets                                1
11          9           8           Mens Clothing                          2
11          8           NULL        Mens Wear                              3
```